# CPU spikes on small site- possibly apache or php config related

Tags: php, central-processing-unit, apache-2.2, httpd.conf, php.ini

I hope you can help me.  I have a site that I'm moving to a new datacenter.  The server is pretty much vanilla, no control panel, and also no optimizations.  When I hit a page, the site takes an extremely long time to load, despite it being relatively light weight.  I ran top to see what was happening, and the cpu jumps to 75%, and drops back down to about 20% while the rest of the page is loading.

Someone suggested that I ran lsof -p on the offending processes, but I'm not sure what I'm looking at.  I ran through my httpd.conf file and commented out a bunch of loaded modules that didn't seem necessary, but that didn't help either.  Anyone have any ideas?

Output of the lsof
http://pastebin.com/mfa113f

Comment: In my /etc/resolv.conf file there are two entries for nameservers, both of the addresses ping ok.

Comment: Which process consumes the most CPU during a spike? Is that Apache or maybe MySQL? What is your memory use? (try running `free -h`) And what is the CPU? Even 20% CPU use looks like too much to me...

Answer (score 1):

For sure it is not a DNS issue. The CPU would be low and the time to load would by consistent with DNS timeout.

In MPOV I think it is a php related issue. The best place to start for performance is to do some profiling of the page with problem. If you are using a CMS, try to test a separate page that is not part of the CMS. Just create a php with:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

and see how long it takes to load this page.
Do you have a database service? Is it located on the same machine?
For general performance profiling you can use:

```
dstat -ta -M topcpu,topio
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the apache log file storing Fully Qualified Domain Names, and if so does your /etc/resolv.conf work as expected?

If FQDN is the problem, turn them off within the config file, and you will find things move a lot faster.

Comment: Right now I don't have a domain name pointing to the server.  I want to get everything working properly before I flip the DNS switch, so I'm hitting the IP directly.

Comment: Mike, Stephen refers to Apache configuration variable, which - when set to true - will resolve *client* IPs to domain names, if any. However, by default this behavior is turned off.